# Jquery get length of json array

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

I've an issue with a json array row length...

I want to extract the correct length of data-row json (in this case "2")...
If I try to count the length I get the value "1". Why ? How can I get the correct length ?

```
{
    "data-row": {
        "data1": [{
            "firstName": "John",
            "lastName": "Doe"
        }, {
            "firstName": "Anna",
            "lastName": "Smith"
        }, {
            "firstName": "Peter",
            "lastName": "Jones"
        }],
        "data2": [{
            "firstName": "John",
            "lastName": "Doe"
        }, {
            "firstName": "Anna",
            "lastName": "Smith"
        }]
    }
}
```

Comment: How did you try to count the length?

Comment: try  `Object.keys(jsondata.data-row).length`

Comment: Please paste your code, how you count the length.

Answer (score 3):

You have a `Object` and to find length of `Object`

```js
var json = {
  "data-row": {
    "data1": [],
    "data2": []
  }
}


alert(Object.keys(json["data-row"]).length);
```

As you are having `-` in `key` use `json["data-row"]` to access `object`

Comment: can you create a demo for this?

Comment: @AnoopJoshi i have created.

Answer (score 1):

This is the another way to find length. but not right way.

```js
var json = {
  "data-row": {
    "data1": [],
    "data2": []
  }
}
length=0;
$.each(json["data-row"],function(i){
  length++;
});
alert(length);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```